# Remove whitespace from li elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple horizontal nav. I've searched through stack overflow fairly thoroughly and found several answers to how to remove the whitespace between li elements. I've tried adding and removing html elements (writing the li tags in a single line, and adding div tags). I've tried changing the 'display: inline' attribute of my li tags to 'display: block' and 'float: left'. I've also tried several other things as suggested by stack overflow users.

Nothing has worked for me.

I'm sure the solution is simple, but nothing I do seems to work properly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

My html is:

```
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="active">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.nav {
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    }
.nav ul {
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.nav ul li {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 56px;
    background: transparent;
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.nav ul li a {
    color: #333;
    text-transform: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    background: transparent;
    }
.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #333;
    }
.active {
    color: #FFF !important;
    background: #333 !important;
    }
```

Comment: Try reproduce this in jsfiddle.

Comment: So, did any of the answers fix it for you? Please choose one of them as the correct answer, or tell us what you think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use float to align element and clear them after your ul here is a working demo 
 http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/dh5eZ/

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">One</a>        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav ul {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style:none;
}
.nav ul li {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 56px;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
    float:left;
    background:#ccc;
}
.nav ul li a {
    color: #333;
    text-transform: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    background: transparent;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #333;
}
.active {
    color: #FFF !important;
    background: #333 !important;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content:" ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make your `<li>` float left and remove the width:

```
.nav ul li {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 56px;
    background: transparent;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style:none;
}
```

I also added 'none' for list-style, as the bullets will show again once you remove the display.

I wouldn't use negative margins since the above is a more elegant solution and less confusing. IMHO, negative margins are hacks and should only be used as a last resort...

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5dBVg/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
li {
    margin:-2px;
}
```

This will knock back the spacing

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nU3Jr/)

Comment: Why use negative margin if it can fix by proper way!

Comment: @Harish Always nice to have more than one alternative as a fall back

Comment: but avoid using negative margin and positions at affect dom to render slow

Comment: I know its not proper, but as I said, "an alternative"

Answer (score 0):

try adding style to li tag in the style.

```
li {
    margin:-2px;
}
```